# Install HHVM on Ubuntu 16.04 w/install_fastcgi.sh

Tags: ubuntu, hhvm

There does not seem to be a prebuilt HHVM package available for Ubuntu 16.04. It seems in Xenial that they have added HHVM to the universal repos, but installing it that way does not include the install_fastcgi.sh script that was present for previous Ubuntu distros. Does anyone know how to install HHVM on 16.04 in a way that includes that script? Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the HHVM team might just not have prebuilts available yet for Xenial per this [issue](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/issues/141).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, this worked for me:

1. sudo apt update && apt upgrade | sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo
   apt-get autoremove
2. add to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu xenial main
   ```
3. sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install -y hhvm

*this should bring you to hhvm 3.14 which is current*

then run the script which will be available on the install credits.

Comment: this works! thanks! prebuilt package is now available, but HHVM docs have yet to be updated.